# How to update ios13 project to ios14

Tags: ios, xcode

I already have a ios13 project in Xcode 11.6, if I want to use the new ios14 feature, how should I update it in Xcode 12?

Answer (score 1):

Just open your project with Xcode 12 and change the deployment target to iOS 14, then you are good to go.